# Query JSONField for with keys of numerals only

Tags: python, django

I've taken the following example from Django's documentation, except replaced added a key '99':

```
>>> Dog.objects.create(name='Rufus', data={
... 'breed': 'labrador',
...     'owner': {
...         'name': 'Bob',
...         'other_pets': [{
...             'name': 'Fishy',
...         }],
...     },
... })
>>> Dog.objects.create(name='Meg', data={'breed': 'collie', '99': 'FINDME',})

>>> Dog.objects.filter(data__breed='collie')
<QuerySet [<Dog: Meg>]>
```

I want the following to also return the "Meg" Dog:

```
Dog.objects.filter(data__99='FINDME')
```

However, it seems that because my key is an integer, Django doesn't handle this properly. How do I have integer keys that are strings in python jsonfields?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't look like there's a good option. Here's a snippet from django/contrib/postgres/fields/jsonb.py:

```
def as_sql(self, compiler, connection):
    key_transforms = [self.key_name]
    previous = self.lhs
    while isinstance(previous, KeyTransform):
        key_transforms.insert(0, previous.key_name)
        previous = previous.lhs
    lhs, params = compiler.compile(previous)
    if len(key_transforms) > 1:
        return "{} #> %s".format(lhs), [key_transforms] + params
    try:
        int(self.key_name)
    except ValueError:
        lookup = "'%s'" % self.key_name
    else:
        lookup = "%s" % self.key_name
    return "%s -> %s" % (lhs, lookup), params
```

From this, it looks like it tries to turn every key into an integer, and use that as the key if possible.

Here's a hack that you could do to make the query the way you want it:

```
def jsonb_integer_keys_to_str(qs, key):
  return qs.model.objects.raw(qs.query.__str__().replace('-> {}'.format(key), "-> '{}'".format(key)))
```

And use it as such:

```
jsonb_integer_keys_to_str(Dog.objects.filter(data__99='FINDME'), 99)
```

This solution is overly specific, but will work in this case. What it's doing is modifying the postgres sql and putting quotes in the right place.

Comment: Why don't you just store key as an integer as well? instead of `'99': 'FINDME'` use `99: 'FINDME'` i.e. `data={'breed': 'collie', 99: 'FINDME',}`

Comment: Great question! Turns out django turns all json keys into strings :(. I'm not sure why.

Comment: Oh I know why -- because JSON doesn't allow integer keys

Comment: Right, What is your Django version?

Comment: For future readers and for you @theicfire, this will work if you just want to access the (key, value), the internal functionality of integer key is to be `interpreted as an index lookup in an array` (more [here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/functions-json.html#FUNCTIONS-JSON-OP-TABLE)) hence with above hack you won't be able to perform queries such as `data__owner__other_pets__0__name`. So better avoid integer keys.

Comment: I was looking at 1.10, but 1.11 also has the same issue. I think that statement you're pointing to isn't always correct, for example, in my `data__99` query, django is smart enough to know I'm not trying to look at the 99th element of a JsonField (it's not an array)

Answer (score 6):

There is a `wontfix` [Django ticket](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/30566) about this.

It is [documented behavior](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/contrib/postgres/fields/#key-index-and-path-lookups):

> If the key is an integer, it will be interpreted as an index lookup in an array.
>
> If the key you wish to query by clashes with the name of another lookup, use the jsonfield.contains lookup instead.

So the suggested solution is to use [jsonfield.contains](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/contrib/postgres/fields/#std:fieldlookup-hstorefield.contains):

```
Dog.objects.filter(data__contains={'99': 'FINDME'})
```

Anyway I suggest you to avoid numeric keys inside json fields because with the `contains` approach you cannot perform `startswith` and other similar lookups (see this [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50569861/django-postgres-json-field-with-numeric-keys)) such as `Dog.objects.filter(data__99__startswith='FIND')`.